# Is there a plain-text, uncompressed variation of ODT?

Tags: text, format, output, open-source, markup

I am writing a simple Python app that should generate a report by inserting paragraphs. The binary sections in an ODT file (from LibreOffice) are fouling things up. RTF ought to do but RTF isn't open source and I prefer OSS. I want my output to be formatted for paragraphs, indenting, colour, typeface, etc. and be readable by typical common word processors.
I cannot find definitive answers to my very basic noob question.
Which file format saves as; open-source, uncompressed, plain text, ubiquitous, well formatted, markup?
Many thanks to the community.
-- Molly J.